# EQ_SELF_USE_OBJECT Bug

Tags: java, methods, equals

I am writing an equals method in which two names are considered equal if they have the same first, middle, and last names. However, I keep getting the error

> "This class defines a covariant version of the equals() method, but
>   inherits the normal equals(Object) method defined in the base
>   java.lang.Object class.  The class should probably define a boolean
>   equals(Object) method."

and when I change it to Object other as the parameter, I get a "no such method" error.

```
public boolean equals(Name other) {

    boolean sameFirstName = firstName.equals(other.firstName);
    boolean sameMiddleName = middleName.equals(other.middleName);
    boolean sameLastName = lastName.equals(other.lastName);
    if (sameFirstName && sameMiddleName && sameLastName) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overloading the method equals by having a different parameter to type `Object`. The following should work for you.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if(this == object) return true;
    if(!(object instanceof Name)) return false;

    Name other = (Name) object;
    boolean sameFirstName = firstName.equals(other.firstName);
    boolean sameMiddleName = middleName.equals(other.middleName);
    boolean sameLastName = lastName.equals(other.lastName);
    if (sameFirstName && sameMiddleName && sameLastName) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the project description says to name it equals

Comment: @neoiajr12 No problem. Glad I helped. :) If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Object type for parameter which called 'other'. Then do instance of checking and casting. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/3634283)

If you use Java 7 or higher, you can use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName) &&
           Objects.equals(middleName, person.middleName) &&
           Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName);
}
```

And there is an automatically generated equals in IDE:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Person person = (Person) o;

    return !(firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(person.firstName) : person.firstName != null) 
                && !(middleName != null ? !middleName.equals(person.middleName) : person.middleName != null) 
                && !(lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(person.lastName) : person.lastName != null);

}
```

Please notice that there should be NPE check as well.